# Using pdb with alternate Python installation

Tags: python, pdb

I have two Python installations on my computer, Python 2.7 in `/usr/bin` and Python 3.3 installed under Miniconda.

I would like to debug using `pdb` on the command line e.g. `$ pdb main.py` and for it to run using the Python 3.3 version instead of the Python 2.7 version.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to invoke a module as a script:

```
/where/is/my/python -m pdb main.py
```